# How do you reset the armature pose back to rest position?

Tags: rigging

I have searched up this before and almost all the answers say "Clear all transform" or "CTRL A and set and rest position". None of these work. I tried ALT+R, ALT+G, and ALT+S, and those don't work. I am using blender 2.8.

Comment: have you selected all the bones in Pose mode before alt R/alt S/alt G?

Comment: Yes moonboots, i have, when i do it it just sends it to a weird position, not rest position

Comment: maybe share the file (the armature only)? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: how do i do armature only?